# MapReduce Task jumping from 0% to 100% right away with no output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm trying to implement a basic MapReduce Java program to find out the max temperature from a given data set. My Map is showing up as executing in incremental steps(0%, 10%, 18%, 27%, ... 100%), but my Reducer task is directly jumping from 0% to 100%. Do you notice any issues with my code below?
Expected Output is weather station code, and max temperature

Sample Data:
Format: WeatherStationCode,YYYYMMDD,ELEMENT,TEMP(multiplied by 10),....

> CA004018880,20010101,TMIN,-220,,,C,

MaxTemperatureMapper.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] dataArray = value.toString().split(",");
        String stationCode = dataArray[0];
        String year = dataArray[1].substring(0, 4);
        String element = dataArray[2];
        int temperature;
        String qualityFlag = dataArray[5];
        String sourceFlag = dataArray[6];

        if(!dataArray[3].isEmpty()) {
            temperature = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[3]);
        } else {
            temperature = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(temperature + "-temperature|");  
        System.out.println(stationCode + "-stationCode|");  

        if(qualityFlag.isEmpty() && sourceFlag.isEmpty() && element.equalsIgnoreCase("TMAX")) {
            context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(temperature));
        }
    }

}
```

MaxTemperatureReducer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class MaxTemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int maxTemp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(IntWritable value: values) {
            maxTemp = Math.max(maxTemp, value.get());
        }
        context.write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(maxTemp));
    }
}
```

MaxYearTemperature.java

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class MaxYearTemperature {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(args);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] programArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if(programArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemp <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, " Max Temp");
        job.setJarByClass(MaxYearTemperature.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(programArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(programArgs[1]));

        //Submit the job and wait for it to finish
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many reducers did you specify?  If it's 1, then you can only go from 0% to 100%.

Comment: Not clear what `key.toString().split(",")[0]` is trying to do, but look at the YARN UI for errors on the tasks

Comment: Removed key.toString().split(",")[0] and just passing key now. First time writing a map reduce program, tried different things, left it from one of the trials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out,
nothing to do with jumping from 0-100% actually,
One of the array values I'm reading from the split array is always empty in the data set and the control is never getting inside the if condition to set the context. 
Once I corrected, it started working.
Thank you for your time.